# What's the Maximum Size of a PE Section?

Tags: windows, portable-executable

Same as title, I'm trying to find out what is the max size of the PE section, I've read all the PE and libloaderapi documentations from Microsoft, and I cannot find any information about the maximum section size, or is the PE section have maximum size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total size limit of a PE file is 4 GiB (Windows will refuse to run it if it is any larger). I would imagine that the section size limit is somewhat close to 4 GiB.